# Did Yoga Vasistha influence Inception?

Tags: analysis, reference, inception

[Yoga Vasistha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_Vasistha) is a scripture of sanathan dharma, aka. Hinduism.

It has a vast explanation of the relativity of space and time, and also talks about dreams, reality, illusion, and other aspects in great detail.

I came across [several](http://www.criticaltwenties.in/philosophyreligionculture/inception-and-its-inspirations-escher-dali-and-yoga-vasistha) [articles](https://natureofperception.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/inception-and-the-yoga-vasishta/amp/) across the internet stating that the scripture was an influence for *Inception*. But is there any official announcement or statement by the creators about the influence of the scripture?

Comment: Why am I getting downvotes? Is it off-topic here?

Comment: Or did I ask in the wrong way?

Comment: I don't know why you're getting downvotes, to be honest; this seems like a perfectly fine question to me. It's definitely not off-topic, and I'll note that nobody has voted to close it yet. We had a similar question about *The Matrix* a couple of days ago that sparked some... drama, shall we say, so it's possible that people are just a bit tetchy about these sorts of questions.

Comment: Insightful question ; wouldn't be surprised if Nolan confessed about having inspiration from Asian culture ( https://www.theguardian.com/film/2014/dec/25/movies-embraced-hinduism )

Comment: @F1Krazy Take some of the various SE sites, their top 100 users and check their ratio up/down votes... Why so much difference... that's interesting.

Comment: It's not new to be Western Movies inspired from East. Take for The Matrix, it was also inspired from Vedas.

Comment: It would be great if downvotes came with some sort of explanation.

Comment: It may be that it was asked at the wrong time @iandotkelly. There are more and more absolutely ridiculous claims made by extremist Hindus and perhaps they (the downvoters) fallaciously assume guilt by association. To imply Inception, a venerably regarded masterpiece in Asia as "it was our idea after all" and to give credibility to their sources in the first place. That, or the fact that there are a myriad of things Inception specially is claimed to be inspired from for some reason. I personally haven't voted either way and think it's a valid question.

Comment: In all honesty, when it comes to Inception, people for some reason seem to treat dreams, illusions or alternate realities as this seldom explored niche topic, but they're certainly not. Alternate realities is all over fiction, most explored in hard SciFi. Illusions have been a hot topic of discussion for millenia, and I'd be surprised if any culture old enough wouldn't have literary works or similar to reference. That said, like most things, it'd probably true that all of the recent ideas about them build on older resources including Hindu sources, not any work in particular.